# React-bootstrap setup for latest kriasoft/react-starter-kit

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-starter-kit

I am a bit new to the world of ReactJS but I have been coding in Javascript for a while now. 
Loving what ReactJS is doing as I was coding in pure JS before using Design Patterns and OOP I consider this a HUGE upgrade for me.

I have followed several tutorials and read A LOT about React, so I ended up starting my first App using `kriasoft/react-starter-kit` in order to boost my productivity, also I find it good that I can have some guideline on how is the "right" way of writing react.

I have stuck while trying to integrate [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) into the existing Starter-kit from kriasoft.

I can import different components from React-Bootstrap (such us Buttons etc.)
by simply

`import Button from '../../../node_modules/react-bootstrap';`

in a component of my own, my problem is that I have no css on those React- Bootstrap components.

I have already gone through the React-Bootstrap getting started guide, but I was not so bright to figure out what I am doing wrong.

I have installed `react-bootstrap` using 
`$ npm install react-bootstrap --save`
but I am not sure where I should include the latest compiled and minified CSS from bootstrap

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="maxcdn....blahblah....bootstrap.min.css">`.

Would be great if someone could help me setting this up by providing a guide or some intuition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also consider looking into `create-react-app` https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

It's a starter kit built by the React team. It simplifies your workflow and lets you focus on learning/creating your react project.

To answer your question, once you install it via `npm`, You can use it via

`import { Button, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'`

Then you can use it in your render

```
<Row>
    <Col md={6}>
        <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large">Submit</Button>
    </Col>
</Row>
```

**For Bootstrap css**

The simplest way would be to use the cdn version of bootstrap css in your index.html file.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />`

But if you want to import it as part of your build process, you'll need to install bootstrap `npm install --save bootstrap` since `react-bootstrap` doesn't come with the css file. Then import it as

`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';`

You need to make sure your webpack is using css-loader.

Comment: Do you know if I can use themes upon the default Bootstrap css ?

Comment: Updated my answer with info about including css

Comment: Do you recommend any other UI  libraries that I should use instead of Bootstrap?
I am already familiar with it Bootstrap so maybe I should try material UI for this project. (Learning is always good) 
I am open to any other suggestions.

Comment: Choosing a UI library is a matter of personal choice and the needs of your project. I just use Bootstrap since it works for my needs.

Aside from Material UI, there's also another React UI framework that I saw http://blueprintjs.com/

Comment: @PaschalidisChristos Please check out http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

I've noticed you have a bunch of other questions that you haven't accepted an answer to. It helps the community to easily filter out answered and unanswered questions.